# SQL Server Database Table relationship

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a question with relationship about my tables in a SQL Server database. Let's say I am working on a Windows Forms application about school. I have four tables and they are teacher, student, application, and class which all four of them have their unique primary key. In my class table, I have the foreign key studentId which means I made the relationship between these two table. Now teacher, application, and teacher left alone.

Here is a database diagram:

[image]

I am wondering if I should do something like this below. I am going to create another new table call allUser_detail and I like all three FK together so they have a relationship?

[image]

Comment: What is the question? should you do it? The answer is yes, if you need it!

Comment: Why not link Teacher detail to class detail?

Comment: @Daniel, It is because in my windows form application, I am trying to filter teacher and student by the applicationName (use as a comboBox)

Comment: The class_detail should not have the foreing key to Student, it is the contrary.
And the 5th table, it should be pointing to class, not student, if you want students of a teacher, just join the tables

Comment: exactly what i said :), i mean, its ok, you have 4 entities (class, student, application and teacher) now you have to make de relations:
1 class has N students?
1 student has N classes?
1 teacher has N Classes?
etc...

i think these are the relations
N classes have N students
1 teacher, with 1 application have 1 class,

Comment: write down all relationships in short english sentences (or whatever language you prefer). and if you are done, check if you can find them in your diagram. example: a teacher teaches several classes. a student attends several classes. a class uses one or more applications.

Comment: but isn't student should be related to class because let say I am grade 9 and have 90 students in that grade, then it should link to this isn't it?

Comment: True, then 1 class has N students, so the foreign key should be in the student table

Comment: @Aツ, thanks I will give this a try

Comment: @IsmaelFuentes, I will look at what I can do from here, thanks

Comment: :) think hard on what relations you need, gl

Comment: @IsmaelFuentes, I have come up with this, see if this make sense to you. `1 class N student`, `1 student N class`, `N class N student`, `N class have 1 teacher`, `1 application N class, N student, N teacher`. I think this is it

Comment: Ok, Summarizing:
Student (N) ---- (N) Class ;; 
Class(N) ----- (N) Application ----- (N) Teacher.

Then you have 4 entities (then 4 tables), one relation N-N (then you need one more table for that relation with both ids) and one ternary relationship (then you need one table with the 3 ids of each one). 

I think this is what you want for your app :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not a clear concept of relationship and foreign key.

A classroom is made of several students and a student can be in only one classroom.

So, you have to specify a column classId in the Student table (and not vice-versa), and assign a foreign key from this column towards the Class table to bind students to a certain class.

Comment: So do you mean, in my class_detail, I will have studentId as my foreign key and in my student_detail table, I will have classId as my foreign key? Will it be a N to N relationship?

Comment: No, you don't need a studentId in class_detail, The correct direction in a one-to-many relation is from the table containing many rows towards the table with the single row. So, you have to specify only classId in the student_detail table, and not the studentId in the class_detail table.

Comment: umm. i see, thanks :)

Comment: Hi Sergio, I have one more question, now what if I have teacher and class relationship and I say "1 teacher can teach many class". Will my my teacherId going to be placed in my class_detail as a foreign key?

Comment: `http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561` this is what I understand from this website

Comment: No; it's not a good idea. Because this means to duplicate class rows, one for each teacher assigned to the class. In this case you have to create a relationship teacher-class (that is, another table containing the two primary keys). This relationship is described by the verb "teaches in". This table has two foreign keys, one towards the class table (classId), and the other towards the teacher table (teacherId). In this way, you will have to duplicate only the rows in the relationship (one for each teacher assigned to the class).